# GET_LIST is overriding GET_ONE request

Tags: react-admin

problem is when `GET_LIST` request taking time, and we change the path like to go to show or edit page

in admin-on-rest we had `cancelPrevious` but now I'm not sure if we have it in `react-admin` anymore

this is reproducible when you have difference between what we loading in GET_LIST request in compare with GET_ONE

for example for GET_LIST you have

```
[{ id, createdAt}, {...}]
```

and for GET_ONE you have whole data like

```
{id, createdAt, deletedAt, content, ...rest}
```

expected behavior is when GET_ONE is triggered it should cancel GET_LIST

Answer (score 3):

That's not how react-admin works. React-admin expects that both `GET_LIST` and `GET_ONE` return the same kind of *entities*, and stores these entities in the same place. React-admin uses the entities from `GET_LIST` to optimistically render the details of an entity, and the entity from `GET_ONE` to optimistically render the list of an entity.

If you want to serve different fields in `GET_ONE`, then you should write your own `List` component to render the list in a pessimistic way, i.e. wait for the server to return the up to date entities to show them.

I do not recommend it however. End users prefer waiting a long time once instead of waiting several times. So in general, they don't mind waiting a little longer for the list if they can get to the details faster. So I recommend that you include the same fields in the `GET_LIST` response as in the `GET_ONE` response.

Comment: what about **cancelPrevious** ? is it possible to cancel requests out of the box?

Comment: No, we've removed that possibility as it caused nasty side effects.